# Regex to mach Github commit URL.

Tags: regex, git

I'm quite new to regex and I'm trying to create a regular expression that matches commit URL on GitHub, for example, a string like this should be matched:

https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/8dc765d438f1e42b3e8227b3b09fad7d73f4ec9a

Is this a correct way to do this?:

```
https://github.com/.*/.*/commit/[0-9a-f]{40}
```

I only need to match links starting with 'https'.

Answer (score 1):

Your pattern is fine, but you could make it more generic by allowing any number of paths between the domain and the `commit` ending portion:

```
https://github\.com(?:/[^/]+)*/commit/[0-9a-f]{40}
```

### Demo

Comment: When matching any number of path elements the why not use the simpler `https://github\.com/.*/commit/[0-9a-f]{40}` ?

Comment: @A.H. Perhaps because that would allow empty path elements.